# How to scroll to a newly added dom element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say the user is viewing a particular part of the page, when behind the scenes an auto update feature runs, and right above or below the user's screen some more content is added.

I have the id of the newly added content's div.

How can I smoothly scroll the user to the newly added div using jquery or plain javascript? Must work in all major browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I use for jQuery

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#ID").offset().top},'slow');
```

Comment: This works, is there also a way to scroll down/up 100 px or so from whatever the user's currently looking at?

Comment: $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#ID").offset().top - 100},'slow');

Answer (score 1):

I think, this should work...with jquery.

```
$(window).scroll($('#newly-added-elem').offset().top);
```

**UPDATE**: smooth scrolling can be achieved with this:

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop: $('#newly-added-elem').offset().top},'slow');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an anchor:

```
<a name="newelement">.... new element stuff here ...</a>
```

then change the page's URL to point at that new element:

```
http://example.com/yourpage.html#newelement
```

Comment: (I didn't downvote) I think it was downvoted because the question was how to animate the action ("smoothly scroll") and this does not do that.

Comment: No biggie. I interpreted the question as "all browsers", not "all MAJOR browsers" - all browsers would mean using old-school techniques.

Comment: I downvoted because I had asked how to scroll to the given element's id, but your method is using the old `<a name=>` technique

Comment: @click: easy enough to prepend a name anchor before the element, especially since you have its id. but no biggie either way.